# Limit of the sequence $v_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

For $A=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} \  \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} \ \frac{2}{3} \end{pmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ Define,  $v_1=v$ and $v_{n+1}=Av_n$ Show that, $lim_{n\to \infty}v_n$ exists and equal to $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+b}{2} \\ \frac{a+b}{2} \end{pmatrix}$.

My attempts:

I just got that the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable and the diagonal matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} \  0 \\ 0 \ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and I got the corresponding eigenvectors $v=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ correspondin to $1$ and $v=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ corresponding to $\frac{1}{3}$.

Now I am stuck. Can anyone please give me some hints that how to proceed with it further?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Can you find a formula for $v_n$ in terms of $v_1$ and $A^n$? What do you know about powers of matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend, since $A$ is symmetric, using an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors:
$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ -1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$
In order to fully transform the problem in terms of this eigenbasis, we should transform $v$ in terms of this basis. The nice thing about orthonormal bases is that we can easily do this with dot products, using
$$v = (v \cdot e_1)e_1 + (v \cdot e_2)e_2 = \left(\frac{a + b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)e_1 + \left(\frac{a - b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)e_2.$$
So, using linearity of $A$, and the fact that $e_1, e_2$ correspond to eigenvalues $1$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ respectively,
$$A^nv = \left(\frac{a + b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)1^ne_1 + \left(\frac{a - b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\frac{1}{3^n}e_2 \to \left(\frac{a + b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)e_1 = \frac{a + b}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

Following your solution, define

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ -1 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

as the matrix of eigenvectors.  Now you can express

$A = P D P^{-1}$

The solution of the recursive relation is

$ v_n = A^{n-1} v_1 $

Now, $A^{n-1} = P D^{n-1} P^{-1}$

The limiting matrix $A^{\infty} = P D^{\infty} P^{-1} $

and $D^{\infty} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Note that $P^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 \\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Putting it all together,

$ A^{\infty} = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ - 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 \\1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

This evaluates to

$ A^{\infty} = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence, $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} v_n  = A^{\infty} v_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} a + b \\ a + b \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $D^n=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3^n} && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now after taking $n\to \infty$ you get $D^\infty$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.